# objective-c use static variable to set default value of controls

Tags: objective-c, static, macros, default-value

Things is like this. I customize a control, adding a piece of view and I give it a `tag` say `111` and a color `[UIColor clearColor]` as the default value.

Of course I can write the configuration code in the `init` method to change the tag number and default color when I want to.

But I want put the code that custom the control together, so I can do the work more quickly.
So I did this:

```
#define kDefaultTag (111)
#define kDefaultColor [UIColor clearColor]
```

and this:

```
+ (int)defaultTag {
    return 111;
}
+ (UIColor *)defaultColor {
    return [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

and this:

```
static int defaultTag;
+ (int)defaultTag {
    defaultTag = 111;
    return defaultTag;
}
```

**Which way is the best practice or none? Is it necessary?**

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I can think of no reason to store defaults like this in static variables if you're going to compile in the values.

Comment: 2 makes the most sense -- would be well-behaved with few surprises -- though you might want to use `#define` statements in a .h somewhere to actually specify the literal values. 3 makes little sense -- why have a static if you set it on every reference.

Comment: @trojanfoe I want put the customizable code together, maybe in the beginning part of the .h or .m file. So the next time I want to change the behavior or appearance, I can modify the code faster. I want to learn the best practice for doing this. Maybe the question title is not quite appropriate. I made that title because I thought the static variable should be used.